# Java Selenium NoSuchElementException not thrown

Tags: java, selenium, exception

I am pretty new with java with selenium and got a question regarding the NoSuchElementException:

I got the following method which should return a WebElement:

```
public WebElement getElementByXpath(String xpath, WebDriver driver) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Test");
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("Element not found");
    }

    return null;
}
```

So what I want is, that if the Element is not found than only "Element not found" will be printed. But instead of this I get the full Error Message, but no "Element not found":

```
Test
2022-03-07 16:22:33.159 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@id='sr_creg_country123']/option[contains(text(), 'Deutschland')]"}
(Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.80)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
.
. 
.
```

As I understand it the Exception will not be thrown, because the Message "Element not found" is never printed?
But can someone explain me why and what do I have to do that the code in the catch-block will be executed?

Cheers,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `NoSuchElementException` exceptions in `Java`, one is in `java.util` and the other is in `org.openqa.selenium`. In order to catch `WebDriver` `NoSuchElementException` exception you need to define the catch explicitly `catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e)` as following:

```java
public WebElement getElementByXpath(String xpath, WebDriver driver) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Test");
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("Element not found");
    }

    return null;
}
```

Alternatively you can import the exception you want to use

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
```

So that your method code can remain without changes:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException

public WebElement getElementByXpath(String xpath, WebDriver driver) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Test");
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("Element not found");
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Great! I'm happy I could help you!